# Problem with imagery extents returned by ArcGIS-REST server in QGIS

Tags: qgis, arcgis-rest-api

I am using the ArcGIS REST server for the Department of Resources, Queensland within QGIS 3.20.2-Odense and keep getting a mismatch between the extent of the imagery and the extent of the map-canvas.

https://gisservices.information.qld.gov.au/arcgis/rest/services/Imagery/QldBase_AllUsers/ImageServer

This happens if I add the imagery using either the AusMap plugin, or directly using Add Layer -> ArcGIS REST Server

Only the eastern most 25% of the image shows up on the map-canvas, the rest is blank.

I don't have the same issue when using the ArcGIS REST servers, such as Google.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: [Works for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djx8v.png) Can you edit your question and specify what version of QGIS and how you are adding the ImageServer.

Comment: Added the QGIS version and specified how I'm adding the layer

Comment: Are you adding it to a blank project?

Comment: It happens when I add to an existing project, or add to a blank project. It looks like the full image appears for a fraction of a second then it either disappears (when I added to a new project) or displays on the eastern 25%.

Comment: Sorry, no idea. It just works for me. Can you post a screenshot? Perhaps look at the network log (View-Panels-Debugging/Development Tools).